# Datediff - Find out the # of working days between 'x' and 'y' using a calendar table for reference

Tags: sql, calendar, ssms, datediff

I have read so many Stack Overflow solutions but I cannot seem to apply them correctly to my query.

Here is my logic statement for reference;

- count the # of days between `dateStageChangedToPendingApproval` to `dateApprovalReceived` (datediff)
- when `'ApprovalRequiredFrom'` = `GRM renewal` for all requests completed in previous month (February) excluding outliers
- and then take the average (exclude holidays & weekends).
- Match date to `Calendar_Date` and if `Day_Name = 'Sunday'` or `'Saturday'` then exclude from the datediff count.

Here is my query that I have started but I am fairly new to SQL and this has been my most challenging task to date.

My query;

```
SELECT AVG(1.00 * DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy)) AS Avg_DayDiff

FROM Database1.dbo.table1

where  
       month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
       and dateStageChangedToPendingApproval < dateApprovalReceived      


join( 

select  CALENDAR_DATE,
        DAY_NAME,
        YEAR(CALENDAR_DATE) AS cal_year,
        MONTH(CALENDAR_DATE) AS cal_month

from Database1.dbo.table1

where month(CALENDAR_DATE) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
      and year(CALENDAR_DATE) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
```

calendar table data sample;

```
Calendar_Date / Day_Name 

2018-02-01 00:00:00:000 / Thursday
2018-02-02 00:00:00:000 / Friday
2018-03-02 00:00:00:000 / Saturday
2018-04-02 00:00:00:000 / Sunday
```

Comment: First, I would build a query that will pull back the days you want to calculate, then run an `avg()`. You want to make sure that your data matches your expectations before you obscure it with an aggregate.

Comment: And one of the points of a calendar table is to pre-calculate all of the info related to a date that you will regularly use. Then you can join your date onto that calendar table and filter by your requirements from your calendar table. This will minimize the amount of date math you'll have to do in your query.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand's calendar table example is one of the better ones I've found. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: And are you working with Microsoft SQL? Which version and flavor?

Comment: What exactly is your average measuring days of?

Answer (score 1):

I have attached my answer as a basis to working with the Calendar Table / Date Dimension. As I said in my comment above, one of the main purposes of a calendar table is to pre-calculate data points (especially date-math-related) so you don't have to repeat them in your query.

**NOTE:** A Calendar Table / Date Dimension is a very handy thing to have in almost any database. I'd suggest creating a permanent one with commonly needed data points to use in your queries. There are numerous examples of creating one.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/720ad/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
/********** TEST DATA for 2018 ***********/
CREATE TABLE t1 ( primaryKey int identity, whoDat varchar(10), approvalRequiredFrom varchar(10), datecompleted date ) ;
INSERT INTO t1 ( whoDat, approvalRequiredFrom, datecompleted )
SELECT 'Jay', 'GRM', datecompleted
FROM (
    SELECT datecompleted = DATEADD(day, rn - 1, '20180101')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, '20180101', '20190101')) 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.object_id
    ) AS x
) AS y;


/* Make data more "random" */
/* "Randomly" create holes in data -- "Delete every 3rd record" */
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE primaryKey%3=0 ;
/* "Randomly" change the approvalRequiredFrom */
UPDATE t1 SET approvalRequiredFrom = 'Bob' WHERE primaryKey%5=0 ;
/* "Randomly" create more holes in data */
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE approvalRequiredFrom = 'GRM' AND DAY(dateCompleted)%3 = 0 ;
```

Now build the Calendar Table. You'll want to come up with a way to calculate the holidays for your time frame.

```
/*******************CALENDAR*******************/
/* The calendar table is for general use in your database, so add whatever calculations you need. */
/* dim is just a holding table for intermediate calculations. */
CREATE TABLE #dim (
      theDate           date        PRIMARY KEY
    , theDay            AS DATEPART(day, theDate)           --int
    , theWeek           AS DATEPART(week, theDate)          --int 
    , theMonth          AS DATEPART(month, theDate)         --int
    , theYear           AS DATEPART(year, theDate)          --int
    , yyyymmdd          AS CONVERT(char(8), theDate, 112)   /* yyyymmdd */
    , mm_dd_yy          AS CONVERT(char(10), theDate, 101)  /* mm/dd/yyyy */
);

/****************************************************************************************************************/
/* Use the catalog views to generate as many rows as we need. */

INSERT INTO #dim ( theDate ) 
SELECT d
FROM (
    SELECT d = DATEADD(day, rn - 1, '20180101')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, '20180101', '20190101')) 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.object_id
    ) AS x
) AS y;

/* Now create the final ref table for the dates. */
CREATE TABLE refDateDimension
(
      DateKey             int         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , theDate             date        NOT NULL
    , theDay              tinyint     NOT NULL  
    , theMonth            tinyint     NOT NULL
    , theYear             int         NOT NULL
    , isWeekend           bit         DEFAULT 0
    , isHoliday           bit         DEFAULT 0
    , isWorkDay           bit         DEFAULT 0
);

/* Insert data in the dimension table. */
INSERT INTO refDateDimension WITH (TABLOCKX)
SELECT
      DateKey              = CONVERT(int, yyyymmdd)
    , theDate              = theDate
    , theDay               = CONVERT(tinyint, theDay)
    , theMonth             = CONVERT(tinyint, theMonth)
    , theYear              = theYear
    , isWeekend            = CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,theDate) IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    , isHoliday            = CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN theDate IN ('2018-01-01','2018-07-01','2018-12-25') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /* New Years, Independence Day and Christmas. Calc others. */
    , isWorkday            = NULL
FROM #dim
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

/* If not a weekend or holiday, it's a WorkDay. */
UPDATE refDateDimension 
SET isWorkDay = CASE WHEN isWeekend = 0 AND isHoliday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
;

/* CLEANUP */
DROP TABLE #dim ;
/****************************************************************************************************************/
```

Now that you've got your test data and a Calendar Table, you can link them together to get the measurements that you're looking for. I didn't know exactly what you were trying to calculate the average dates for, so I showed you the average number of of records with `datecompleted` during a given range.

**Query 1**:

```
/* This will give you an average number of days per month for the time period specified. */
SELECT s1.theYear, s1.theMonth, avg(recordCount) AS Avg_DayDiff
FROM (
  SELECT dd.theYear, dd.theMonth, count(*) AS recordCount
  FROM refDateDimension dd 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON dd.theDate = t1.datecompleted
    AND t1.ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
  WHERE t1.datecompleted >= '2018-03-01'
    AND t1.datecompleted <= '2018-11-10' 
  GROUP BY dd.theYear, dd.theMonth
) s1
GROUP BY s1.theYear, s1.theMonth
ORDER BY s1.theYear, s1.theMonth
```

**[Averages By Month](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/720ad/1/0)**:

```
| theYear | theMonth | Avg_DayDiff |
|---------|----------|-------------|
|    2018 |        3 |           8 |
|    2018 |        4 |          16 |
|    2018 |        5 |          17 |
|    2018 |        6 |           8 |
|    2018 |        7 |           9 |
|    2018 |        8 |           8 |
|    2018 |        9 |          16 |
|    2018 |       10 |          17 |
|    2018 |       11 |           3 |
```

Before you try to calculate average days, I'd suggest you simply run a query to pull the number of days that you are looking to average. You might notice some days that were missed or something. For instance, just looking at my averages, I see that there were much fewer days in June, July and August. I don't know if that's because I eliminated them from my test data or if there's an issue with my query. Looking at the data will help figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(Cnt)
FROM (SELECT requestID, COUNT(*) Cnt
      FROM table1 t
      JOIN calendarTable ct ON t.dateStageChangedToPendingApproval >= ct.Calendar_Date
                           AND t.dateApprovalReceived < ct.Calendar_Date                        
      WHERE MONTH(datecompleted) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,current_timestamp))
      AND YEAR(datecompleted) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,current_timestamp))
      AND ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
      AND ct.Day_Name NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
      GROUP BY requestID
     ) A
```

- `JOIN` to your calendar table to get a record for each day, per request
- Filter the records to not include weekends
- `COUNT()` the records remaining to get the number of non-weekend days per request
- Wrap the query in an `AVG()`

**Notes**: First, you mention also needing to rule out holidays.  To do that, include a 'holiday' boolean or something similar in your calendar table that you can filter on.  Second, I used `>=` for the start date, and `<` for the end date.  That's because `DATEDIFF()` between two days = 1, and using the equals operators on both sides would essentially add an extra day. Last, I removed your outlier catch from the `WHERE` clause because the `JOIN` predicate now handles it.